# ASP.Net Login Form doesn't login

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an VB.NET login form that was created using the form templates.

The form logs in on my live server, but doesn't work on my test server.

The form loads fine at first, (It loads the page) but once I click login the request just hangs.

My server setup:

- I am using IIS 7
- Windows 2008 R2 Web Server.
- SQL Server 2012

All the users are stored in the database, and I am not using Windows based Authentication.

The IIS user has Full Access over the website folder, as does the Identity Pool. I have checked the credentials using the IIS manager, and both can connect without any warnings or errors.

[image: Example of the request hanging]

What could cause this problem?

I have checked the following:

- The database connection is active and the user does have full permissions to login
- There are no errors in the log files and no errors are displayed.

This is the VB code behind the login form.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity
Imports UserDetails


Partial Class Account_Login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim users As MembershipUserCollection

    Sub OnLoggedIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Try
            Response.Redirect("~/TermsAndConditions.aspx")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

The ASP code for the form

```
<%@ Page Title="Log In" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeFile="Login.aspx.vb" Inherits="Account_Login" Debug="true" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="siteMenu" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <center>

    <asp:Label ID="lblLogin" runat="server" Text="Log In" CssClass="HeadingStyle" Width="100%"/>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false" OnLoggedIn="OnLoggedIn" DefaultButton="LoginButton">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <span class="failureNotification">
                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </span>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
                 ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
            <div class="accountInfo" style="width:600px">
                <fieldset class="login">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" Text="Account Information" CssClass="NormalLable" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False" Font-Size="17px" Width="100%"/>
                    <table style="line-height:1px; border-collapse:collapse; width:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" Text="Username / Kode:" CssClass="NormalLable"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="NormalTextbox" AutoCompleteType="Search" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                                     CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." 
                                     ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">Enter a username to continue</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" Text="Password / Wag woord:" CssClass="NormalLable"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="NormalTextboxSmall" 
                                    TextMode="Password" AutoCompleteType="Search" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                                     CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." 
                                     ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">Enter a password to continue</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Checked="False" Visible="false" CssClass="NormalTextbox" Text="Keep me Logged in"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
                <p class="submitButton">
                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" CssClass="NormalButton" width="200px" height="40px"/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>
    </center>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Errors in console of browser? What did you debug?

Comment: is the database server different? have you checked the network access between the test web server and the db server? if not, open the test server cmd and run `telnet dbserverip 1433`. if you don't get a blank screen it means that you have no network access

Comment: @Tester, The browser console shows no errors.

Comment: @Ted I checked, the cmd opens a blank window, Ill see if I can enable the network access quickly

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer - a blank window means you HAVE access. so the problem is elsewhere